# Phpunit testing with ZF2 Album Module fails while connecting to AlbumTable

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

I am trying the phpunit in the Zf2 album module by following the online ZF2 tutorial. Below is the debug information.

```
Album\Model\AlbumTableTest::testFetchAllReturnsAllAlbums
Argument 1 passed to Album\Model\AlbumTable::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, instance of Mock_TableGateway_fb3537df given, called in D:\www\zend2\tests\module\Album\src\Album\Model\AlbumTableTest.php on line 26 and defined
```

And the function used is

```
public function testFetchAllReturnsAllAlbums()
{
    $resultSet        = new ResultSet();
    $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway',
                                       array('select'), array(), '', false);
    $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                     ->method('select')
                     ->with()
                     ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

    $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

    $this->assertSame($resultSet, $albumTable->fetchAll());
}
```

And the 26th line mentioned in the debug information is

```
$albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);
```

Which calls to the following functon in Album\Model\AlbumTable::__construct()

```
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
        $this->initialize();
    }
```

Any help to over come this failed test is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. I happened to see that the Album module given in the Zend Framework2 tutorial has been changed. I followed it once again to correct the changed codes. Now the mentioned issue has been sorted out.